# How to save UIImage as a SVG file

Tags: ios, svg, uiimage, uibezierpath

The image draws with bezierPath, and I want to save it as a SVG file.
The format I can see are PNG or JPG.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, at least not while using UIImage. Read the class doc...

[UIImage Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Supported Image Formats
Table 1 lists the file formats that can be read by the UIImage class.

Supported file formats
Tagged Image File Format (TIFF)
.tiff, .tif

Joint Photographic Experts Group (JPEG)
.jpg, .jpeg

Graphic Interchange Format (GIF)
.gif

Portable Network Graphic (PNG)
.png

Windows Bitmap Format (DIB)
.bmp, .BMPf

Windows Icon Format
.ico

Windows Cursor
.cur

X Window System bitmap
.xbm

However, this kit may help...[SVGKit](https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit). It interacts with Core Animation.

Comment: Thank you for you replay.Can I create SVG image from a UIView or from the bezier Path?

Comment: You cannot, however you can render in a UIWebView NSString*path =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image" ofType:@"svg"];
NSURL *fileURL =[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest*req =[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL];
[webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
[webView loadRequest:req]; http://mytechspace.com/2012/03/load-svg-images-in-iphone-ipad-using.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have a bezier path, you do not want to save it via a UIImage. You can convert it directly to an SVG path string, and insert that SVG path into an SVG document.

See for instance this answer: [Converting UIBezierPath to SVG answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30998142/uibezierpath-to-nsdata-to-server-to-android/31328363#31328363)